# Another person doesn't understand the linkage of main.cpp, program_name.cpp and program_name.h

Tags: c++

I've tried to look at old Stack Overflow posts on this matter, but I'm still confused and would greatly appreciate someone explaining to me where I'm going wrong here.

I'm using Apple XCode 3 and I have three files in the "Source" folder of my project. They are calcsteps.cpp, calcsteps.h and main.cpp.

In my main I have `#include "calcsteps.h"`. From my understanding, that literally pastes the contents of `calcsteps.h`, which are merely a bunch of function declarations. There are no directives in that .h file. However, my .cpp file by the same name has a directive to also has the directive `#include "calcsteps.h"`.

**main.cpp:**

```
#include "calcsteps.h"
#include <string>
#include <iostream>

int main (int argc, char* const argv[]) {

    // Evaluate expressions at the console
    std::string eqtn; 
    while (std::cin >> eqtn) {
        if (!valid_equation(eqtn)) { 
            std::cout << "Equation invalid; not evaluated" << std::endl;
        } else { 
            std::cout << evaluate_equation(eqtn) << std::endl;
        }
    }

    return 0;
}
```

**calcsteps.h:**

```
std::string evaluate_equation(std::string);
bool valid_equation(const std::string&); 
int str2Int(const std::string&);
std::string int2Str(unsigned int);
bool isDigit(char);
bool isOp(char);
std::string addStrs(const std::string&, const std::string&);
std::string subtrctStrs(const std::string&, const std::string&);
std::string multStrs(const std::string&, const std::string&);
std::string divStrs(const std::string&, const std::string&);
std::string powStr(const std::string&, const std::string&);
```

**calcsteps.cpp:**

```
#include "calcsteps.h"

#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <algorithm>
#include <math.h>



std::string evaluate_equation(std::string eq) {
    /* By the order of operations: 
     (1) Evaluate the expression in the innermost set of paranthesis;
     (2) Evaluation exponents;
     (3) Evaluate multiplication and division expressions left-to-right;
     (4) Evaluate addition and substraction expressions left-to-right;
     Use recursion. Print out steps.
     */

    // (1): 
    size_t LRFP = eq.find_last_of('('); // position of last right-facing paranthesis
    if (LRFP != std::string::npos) {
        // Set NLFP to be the position of the next left-facing paranthesis after the FRFPL
        size_t NLFP = LRFP; 
        while (eq[++NLFP] != ')'); 
        /* Replace the space between FRFP and NLFP inclusive with the evalulation of the expression 
         between FRFP and NLFP exclusive:
         */
        std::string paranstr = eq.substr(LRFP + 1, NLFP - LRFP - 1);
        std::cout << eq << " -> ";
        eq.replace(LRFP, NLFP - LRFP + 1, evaluate_equation(paranstr));
        std::cout << eq << std::endl;
        return evaluate_equation(eq);
    }
    // (2):
    size_t firstexp = eq.find_first_of('^');
    if (firstexp != std::string::npos) {
        // Set base and power equal to the respective numbers to the left and right of the '^' symbol
        std::string base, power; 
        size_t basebegin(firstexp), powerend(firstexp);
        while (basebegin > 0 && isDigit(eq[basebegin - 1]))  
            base.insert(0, 1, eq[--basebegin]);
        int eqsz = eq.size();
        while ((powerend + 1) < eqsz && isDigit(eq[powerend + 1]))
            power.push_back(eq[++powerend]);
        // Replace the space of the multiplication equation base^power with its evaluation:
        std::cout << eq << " -> ";
        eq.replace(basebegin, powerend - basebegin + 1, powStr(base, power));
        std::cout << eq << std::endl;
        return evaluate_equation(eq);
    }

    // (3):
    size_t firstast(eq.find_first_of('*')), firstslash(eq.find_first_of('/')); // position of first asterisk 
    size_t firstMD = std::min(firstast, firstslash);
    if (firstMD != std::string::npos) {
        // Set num1 and num2 equal to the respective numbers to the left and right of the asterisk:
        std::string num1, num2; 
        size_t num1begin(firstMD), num2end(firstMD);
        while (num1begin > 0 && isDigit(eq[num1begin - 1]))  
            num1.insert(0, 1, eq[--num1begin]);
        int eqsz = eq.size();
        while ((num2end + 1) < eqsz && isDigit(eq[num2end + 1]))
            num2.push_back(eq[++num2end]);
        std::cout << eq << " -> ";
        if (firstMD == firstast) { 
            // Replace the space of the multiplication equation num1*num2 with its evaluation:
            eq.replace(num1begin, num2end - num1begin + 1, multStrs(num1, num2));
        } else { 
            // Replace the space of the division equation num1/num2 with its evaluation:
            eq.replace(num1begin, num2end - num1begin + 1, divStrs(num1, num2));
        }
        std::cout << eq << std::endl;
        return evaluate_equation(eq);
    }
    // (4):
    size_t firstplus(eq.find_first_of('+')), firstminus(eq.find_first_of('-'));
    size_t firstAS = std::min(firstplus, firstminus);
    if (firstAS != std::string::npos) {
        // Set num1 and num2 equal to the respective numbers to the left and right of the asterisk:
        std::string num1, num2; 
        size_t num1begin(firstAS), num2end(firstAS);
        while (num1begin > 0 && isDigit(eq[num1begin - 1]))  
            num1.insert(0, 1, eq[--num1begin]);
        int eqsz = eq.size();
        while ((num2end + 1) < eqsz && isDigit(eq[num2end + 1]))
            num2.push_back(eq[++num2end]);
        std::cout << eq << " -> ";
        if (firstAS == firstplus) { 
            // Replace the space of the addition equation num1+num2 with its evaluation:
            eq.replace(num1begin, num2end - num1begin + 1, addStrs(num1, num2));
        } else { 
            // Replace the space of the subtraction equation num1-num2 with its evaluation:
            eq.replace(num1begin, num2end - num1begin + 1, subtrctStrs(num1, num2));
        }
        std::cout << eq << std::endl;
        return evaluate_equation(eq);
    }
    // If we made it to this point, all that's left of the equation is a single number. Return it; 
    return eq; 
}

bool valid_equation(const std::string& eq) { 
    // Equation cannot be empty: 
    if (eq.empty()) { 
        std::cout << "Equation cannot be an empty string" << std::endl;
        return false;
    }
    std::string::const_iterator it = eq.begin();
    // First character must be a right-facing parenthesis or a digit:
    if (*it != '(' && !isDigit(*it)) { 
        std::cout << "Equation cannot start with " << *it << std::endl;
        return false;
    }
    /* Iterate through the characters of the equation to check that it is valid based on 
     which characters are lined up next to which. For example, if two plus signs are found 
     next to each other, that makes the equation meaningless and the our function 
     valid_equation() immediately returns false.
     */
    // Count for the number of right-facing and left-facing parantheses:
    int RFPcnt(0), LFPcnt(0); 
    while ((it + 1) != eq.end()) { 
        if (isDigit(*it)) { 
            char nextchar = *(it + 1);
            if (!isDigit(nextchar) && !isOp(nextchar)) { 
                std::cout << "Digit cannot be followed by " << nextchar << std::endl;
                return false;
            } else { 
                ++it;
            }
        } else if (isOp(*it)) {
            char nextchar = *(it + 1);
            if (!isDigit(nextchar) && nextchar != '(') { 
                std::cout << "Operator cannot be followed by " << nextchar << std::endl;
                return false;
            } else { 
                ++it;
            }
        } else if (*it == '(') { 

        } else if (*it == ')') { 

        } else { 
            std::cout << "Inavlid character: " << *it << std::endl;
            return false;
        }
    }
    /* At this point, 'it' is the last character in the equation. It must be a digit
     or left-facing parenthesis.
     */
    if (*it != ')' && !isDigit(*it)) { 
        std::cout << "Equation cannot end with " << *it << std::endl;
        return false;
    }

    // Check for unbalanced parentheses
    if (LFPcnt != RFPcnt) { 
        std::cout << "Unbalanced parantheses." << std::endl;
        return false;
    }

    return true; // If we made it here, the equation is valid; return true
} 

// Given a decimal representation as a string s, str2Int(s) returns the corresponding decimal as an int
int str2Int(const std::string& str) {
    std::string::const_iterator it = str.begin();
    if (it == str.end()) { 
        std::cout << "Invalid parameter: str2Int() only accepts non-empty strings." << std::endl; 
        return -1;
    }
    int sum = 0;
    while (it != str.end()) {
        if (!isDigit(*it)) { 
            std::cout << "Invalid parameter: str2Int only accepts strings of chars '0' through '9'" << std::endl;
            return -1;
        } else { 
            sum *= 10;
            sum += *it++ - '0';
        }
    }
    return sum;
}

// Given an int n, int2Str(n) return the string representation 
std::string int2Str(unsigned int n) { 
    std::string retstring; 
    if (n == 0) { 
        retstring.push_back('0'); 
        return retstring;
    } else { 
        while (n != 0) { 
            retstring.insert(0, 1, char('0' + n % 10));
            n /= 10;
        }   
        return retstring;
    }
}

// Function that checks whether a given character is in one of '0', '1', ..., '9'
bool isDigit(char c) { 
    return (c >= '0' && c <= '9');
} 

bool isOp(char c) { 
    switch (c) { 
        case '^': return true;
        case '*': return true;
        case '/': return true;
        case '+': return true;
        case '-': return true;
        default: return false;  
    }
}

// Adds 2 string decimal representations and returns the sum as a string decimal representation
std::string addStrs(const std::string& s1, const std::string& s2) { 
    return (int2Str(str2Int(s1) + str2Int(s2)));
}

// Substracts 2 string decimal representations and returns the result as a string decimal representation
std::string subtrctStrs(const std::string& s1, const std::string& s2) { 
    return (int2Str(str2Int(s1) - str2Int(s2)));
}


// Multiplies 2 string decimal representations and returns the sum as a string decimal representation
std::string multStrs(const std::string& s1, const std::string& s2) { 
    return (int2Str(str2Int(s1) * str2Int(s2)));
}

// Divides 2 string decimal representations and returns the quotient as a string decimal representation
std::string divStrs(const std::string& s1, const std::string& s2) { 
    return (int2Str(str2Int(s1) / str2Int(s2)));
}

/* Raises the string decimal representation s to the string decimal representation p power and returns the 
 result as a string decimal representation.
 */
std::string powStr(const std::string& s, const std::string& p) {
    return (int2Str((int)pow((double)str2Int(s), (double)str2Int(p))));
}
```

When I try to compile calcsteps.cpp, I'm getting errors at all the points where function implementations call other functions. Any advice greatly appreciated.

Comment: and the compile error is...

Comment: Why *on earth* does `main.cpp` have header guards around it???

Comment: For instance, evaluate_equation(...) uses the powStr(...) function, but  where it does I get the error "powStr was not declared in this scope."

Comment: What do you think the very first line the compiler will see after resolving all the include statements?

Comment: Is there a header guard in `calcsteps.h`? Is `string.h` included in the header?

Comment: @NikolaDimitroff: It is 2013, not 1993. We do not use `string.h` any more.

Comment: Is that the first error? The first error is what's important, it often causes a cascade of further errors.

Comment: This has nothing to do with linkage!

Comment: You should `#include <string>` before `#include "calcsteps.h"`

Comment: http://sscce.org -- the question as wr8tten is far to long to be useful.

Comment: @ichramm: It was clear before. All he's done is added a few extra declarations.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit you are right, I missed the part about the file having no declarations, thanks!

Answer (score 1):

**Your `calcSteps.h` does not include the standard headers containing declarations for the standard types you use, such as `std::string`.**

This will result in, among many other error messages, the statement that "`powStr` was not declared in this scope" because `powStr`'s declaration simply could not be understood with those references to unknown standard types.

Even though you did include those headers in `calcsteps.cpp`, you did so *after* including `calcSteps.h`. Since you're absolutely right that `#include` is like a copy-and-paste, those inclusions come too late.

We typically include headers *where we need them* so the standard headers should be included from `calcSteps.h`.

I would also suggest making your filename case convention consistent, and your `calcSteps.h` inclusion guard is currently found in `main.cpp` instead — presumably a typo.